# Filter multivalue property field for multiple objects and export to csv

Tags: powershell, filter, multivalue, export-csv

need to get all ad users with a filter on following properties and then export to csv:

```
Get-ADUser -filter *  -Properties sn, givenname, samaccountname, employeenumber, employeeID,departmentnumber
```

In this cas all default properties is also included. So i tried this:

```
Get-ADUser -filter *  -Properties sn, givenname, samaccountname, employeenumber, employeeID,departmentnumber | select sn, givenname, samaccountname, employeenumber, employeeID,departmentnumber
```

Fine. This is what i want.
Now the problem. When i run this with the export-csv option there is an error in the departmentnumber column.

```
Get-ADUser -filter *  -Properties sn, givenname, samaccountname, employeenumber, employeeID,departmentnumber | select sn, givenname, samaccountname, employeenumber, employeeID,departmentnumber | Export-Csv filexyz.csv
```

Because this is multivalue property it looks like this in the csv file: (i delete all user specific data)

> "sn","givenname","samaccountname","employeenumber","employeeID","departmentnumber"
>   ,**"Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADPropertyValueCollection"**

In CLI Powershell it looks like this: (i delete all user specific data)

> sn               :  givenname        :  samaccountname   : 
>   employeenumber   :  employeeID       :
>   **departmentnumber : {ONR1200402}**

Any idea how to solve this issue for exporting a multivalue property to csv?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your `departmentnumber` property is a `collection` type you could try to `-join` all values together via property expression feature preparing data to `Export-CSV`.

Like so:

```
Get-ADUser -filter *  -Properties sn, givenname, samaccountname, employeenumber, employeeID,departmentnumber | 
    Select-Object sn, givenname, samaccountname, employeenumber, employeeID,@{Name ='departmentnumber';Expression ={$_.departmentnumber -join ';'}} | 
        Export-Csv filexyz.csv
```

Note that I use semicolon (`;`) in my example to join values from departmentnumber collection.

Comment: Thanks for your fast response. This is what i was looking for.  Works fine.